# Does importing exit from sys run the in-built function or the one from the module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, module

If I run this:

```
from sys import exit
exit()
```

Does it run the inbuilt function exit, or sys.exit()?

I am using python 3.8.3

Comment: @rdas There is though. It's meant for the interactive shell but it's also present in scripts. Well really it's an instance of the [`Quitter` class](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/_sitebuiltins.py#L13).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It runs `sys.exit`.

The import overwrites the existing `exit` variable with the `sys.exit` function.

Comment: I see. would there then be a way to run the normal exit() function under the same conditions?

Comment: @TimothyCahill Yes, you can call `__builtins__.exit()`.